# Why are values named differently via xml and code?

Tags: android, naming-conventions

Why are values of properties named differently via xml and code, when they are equivalent?

Like

```
    <EditText
    android:inputType="text" />
```

and

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```

There are lots of other examples - not just InputType. Why the doubling instead of something consistent? Everything needs you to have a matching table on hand.

Comment: the naming conventions are easy to follow, `camelCase` for attributes/properties, `UpperCamelCase` for classes

Comment: i get the naming conventions but not why they chose to have a different set in xml/code. Why use `text` as inputType, when you're in XML, but to get the same result put `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` when doing it from the code. Why don't use `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` as the string to put in the xml android:inputType? That just makes everything more confusing.

Comment: I'm talking about the value of inputType, not the `InputType` name itself. I get why thats in camel and upperCamel.